# How to create compact "silent" 1-time use redstone trigger?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

## Background

I've recently found how to create a 1-time use trigger using a `piston` (must be pointing up) which pushes a `redstone block`:

[image]

The piston was too loud, so I'm currently using a `hopper` with 1 item that feeds into a chest:

[image]

---

## Question

Are there any other "1-time systems", similar to the ones above, that are more compact than the `hopper` system I've shown?

*Even if not more compact, I'm still curious as to other 1-time systems which can be used for builds.*

Comment: Piece of bamboo and string.

Comment: Is it important that it is silent?

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 The only noise should be from what is activated by the user. For example: buttons and trip wire are used to activate, and those make a sound, but that's okay). In this build, sound plays a role, and I cannot have sound in an area unless triggered by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are way too easy - actually so easy they are an active problem when building. "Why does that not unpower?" is way too common a problem. It would be way too much work to list them all but I can post some silent ones.

Probably the simplest is repeater feeding itsef.

[image]

Every common RS latch will be this if you don't connect the R input to anything.

[image]

The classic repeater clocks become this if you trigger them with too long signal

[image]

If you want to use update instead of signal, a BUD'ed dropper with one item in it will react to a block update (and will be quiet when injecting that item into a container). After update it's powered and nothing can unpower it so it won't react to anything else, remaining silent.

[image]

Comment: I feel so silly... Having a repeater feed into itself is an extremely easy solution which is more compact. It's also completely silent, which is perfect. 2 x 2 x 1, not sure how it can get anymore compact than that without relying on upwards piston mechanics. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Dioxin: If you don't need it silent, but want in any direction, not just up, just use a redstone block and non-sticky piston.